# If we locate the xpath from html content then how we find if we can entered text on that particular xpath or not

Tags: python, selenium

If we find xpath from html Content then how to check if we entered the text on that xpath or not. Using python selenium.
Please guide.

I searched on Google but not found any solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Depends on your Element, plase provide a reproducable element.